# Adjust button width to fit any text in a collection view

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uibutton

So my problem is that I have a collection view where I list the product categories. I want to fit the text with different widths into the button. I played around with the constraints a bit and that's the best I got. There is some empty unused spaces at the end of some buttons. How can I adjust the button width to fit the text exactly with no extra spaces? Here is a screenshot explaining the issue exactly.

[image]
This is how I align my components in the view.
[image]

Any suggestions?